# Need a different kernel header with struct net_device to compile MadWifi drivers against

Tags: linux-kernel, debian

I'm pretty new to all of this so sorry about the large amount of nonsense this post is comprised of as I try and word what I want to say.

I am trying to compile the MadWiFi kernel module but unfortunately getting the error below. The problem (AFAIK) is that the kernel headers I am using have a new struct to replace net_device.

Can I use a different set of kernel headers to compile it against or would the resulting module not be compatible with my kernel?

```
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-686/build SUBDIRS=/home/madwifi-0.9.4 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-686'
make[1]: Warning: File `Makefile' has modification time 4.2e+08 s in the future
make[2]: Warning: File `Makefile' has modification time 4.2e+08 s in the future
make[3]: Warning: File `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common/arch/x86/Makefile_32.cpu' has modification time 4.2e+08 s in the future
make[4]: Warning: File `scripts/Makefile.lib' has modification time 3.1e+08 s in the future
make[5]: Warning: File `scripts/Makefile.lib' has modification time 3.1e+08 s in the future
  CC [M]  /home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.o
In file included from /home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/../net80211/ieee80211_monitor.h:45,
                 from /home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:71:
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/../ath/if_athvar.h:98: error: conflicting types for 'irqreturn_t'
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common/include/linux/irqreturn.h:16: error: previous declaration of 'irqreturn_t' was here
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_attach':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:402: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:678: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'open'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:679: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'stop'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:680: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'hard_start_xmit'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:681: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'tx_timeout'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:683: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'set_multicast_list'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:684: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'do_ioctl'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:685: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'get_stats'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:686: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'set_mac_address'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:687: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'change_mtu'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_detach':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:958: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:1005: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'stop'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_vap_create':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:1014: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:1084: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_vap_delete':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:1248: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_suspend':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:1350: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_resume':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:1359: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_intr':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:1652: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_bmiss_tasklet':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:1843: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_init':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:1886: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_stop_locked':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:2014: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_stop':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:2078: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_reset':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:2182: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_tx_startraw':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:2343: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_hardstart':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:2558: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_mgtstart':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:2875: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_key_alloc':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:3237: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_key_delete':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:3304: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_key_set':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:3380: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_key_update_begin':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:3395: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_key_update_end':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:3416: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_mode_init':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:3504: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_updateslot':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:3555: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_beacon_dturbo_config':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:3585: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_beacon_dturbo_update':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:3633: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_turbo_switch_mode':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:3776: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_bstuck_tasklet':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:4368: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_node_alloc':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:4820: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_node_cleanup':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:4855: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_node_free':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:4909: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_rx_capture':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:5404: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_tx_capture':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:5437: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_recv_mgmt':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:5502: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_rx_tasklet':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:5574: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_grppoll_start':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:6013: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_grppoll_stop':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:6226: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_wme_update':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:6441: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_uapsd_flush':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:6460: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_tx_start':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:6655: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_tx_tasklet_q0':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:7495: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_tx_tasklet_q0123':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:7516: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_tx_tasklet':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:7551: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_tx_timeout':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:7574: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_calibrate':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:7937: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_scan_start':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:8003: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_scan_end':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:8023: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_set_channel':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:8041: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_set_coverageclass':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:8057: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_mhz2ieee':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:8067: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_newstate':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:8082: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_setup_stationkey':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:8471: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_newassoc':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:8631: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_getchannels':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:8662: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_xr_rate_setup':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:8832: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_setup_subrates':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:8861: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_rate_setup':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:8904: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_getstats':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9141: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_set_mac_address':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9164: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_change_mtu':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9196: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_ioctl':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9283: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_sysctl_halparam':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9370: error: passing argument 5 of 'proc_dointvec' from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9370: error: too many arguments to function 'proc_dointvec'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9562: error: passing argument 5 of 'proc_dointvec' from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9562: error: too many arguments to function 'proc_dointvec'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: At top level:
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9574: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9580: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9586: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9592: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9598: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9604: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9610: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9616: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9623: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9630: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9636: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9642: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9648: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9654: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9660: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9667: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9673: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9680: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9686: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_announce':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9779: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c: In function 'ath_rcv_dev_event':
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9926: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'priv'
/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.c:9928: error: 'struct net_device' has no member named 'open'
make[5]: *** [/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath/if_ath.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [/home/madwifi-0.9.4/ath] Error 2
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/madwifi-0.9.4] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-686'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

More info on my kernel:

```
root@alix:~# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-5-686 (Debian 2.6.32-45) (dannf@debian.org) (gcc version 4.3.5 (Debian 4.3.5-4) ) #1 SMP Sun May 6 04:01:19 UTC 2012

root@alix:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.5 (squeeze)
Release:    6.0.5
Codename:   squeeze
```

Answer (score 1):

MadWifi is currently maintained at https://github.com/proski/madwifi.  It should support all Linux kernels from 2.6.13 to the latest released kernel (currently 3.12).  MadWifi is in maintenance-only mode.  No new features are accepted, only fixes.  No formal releases are planned.  Use ath5k or ath9k that come with your Linux kernel unless you have a reason not to.

Messages about modification time in the future mean that your computer clock is not set correctly or was incorrect when you unpacked the source.

Answer (score 0):

MadWiFi is deprecated.  ath5k and ath9k are supposedly the replacements, and ship with the kernel.  The errors you are getting are due to changes in the kernel API, and the only way to use your module with your current kernel would be to update the module as necessary, which is not a trivial task.  Stick with the new drivers unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: Can I create a virtual wireless interface with the ath5k driver?